# Draw NSShadow inside a NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsshadow

I'm trying to draw a NSShadow on the background of a NSView. I want to use it as a replacement for NSGradient, as I need to support Mac OS X Tiger. How may I do that? I know this must be pretty easy and I must be making some mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: Expand your question, please. What do you want to "cast" the shadow?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest approach may be to just set the shadow properties for the view's layer. If you have a NSView* named `view`, it'd be something like:

```
[[view layer] setShadowOpacity:0.5];
```

Setting the shadow opacity to something greater than 0 will make the shadow visible. The shadow drawn will be similar to the view's alpha channel, so whatever you draw in the view will have a shadow. There are several other shadow attributes that you can set, such as the blur radius. Take a look at the [CALayer reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more.

If you must use NSShadow, then just set up a shadow before you do your drawing:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSShadow *shadow = [[[NSShadow alloc] init] autorelease];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:3.0];
    [shadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0.0, 5.0)];
    [shadow setShadowColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.6]];
    [shadow set];
    // continue with your drawing...
}
```

Comment: There's no Core Animation on Tiger, that's why I must use NSShadow :(

Comment: Some corrections are needed as this won't compile.  The method name is setShadowBlurRadius.  Also setShadowOffset take an NSSize not a double.